# Reverse enumerating through a random NSArray Objective C

Tags: nsarray, enumeration

I'm currently making an app that plays videos from an array. I've hooked the array up to a randomizer so that when the user hits a "next" button, a video from the array is selected at random. The next button works fine, but what I'm struggling with is the back button. I want the user to be able to return to the previous video by hitting a "back" button. I have researched several ways to do this but none have worked. If someone could take a look at my code below and give me some suggestions That would be greatly appreciated! Take note that I only selected 1 index from the array to save space. Also, I know that there are several other posts about reverse enumeration and like I said, none have brought me success. If done a ton of research and this is my last resort.

```
@implementation MajesticViewController

@synthesize arrayName = _arrayName;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

[super viewDidLoad];


//Heres the array containing the videos

_arrayName = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:

// video 0- losing you

@"<iframe width=\"279\" height=\"199\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/YjvRydejkYY\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>", @"<iframe width=\"279\" height=\"199\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/nosOsDG38nQ?rel=0\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>", nil];    

[self pickSong:_arrayName];

}

//This is the next button

-(IBAction)newSongButton:(id)sender
{

[self pickSong:_arrayName];

}

//This randomly picks the next video

-(void)pickSong:(NSArray *)arrayName

{

int r = arc4random() % 47;

//int r = 46; /////tester

if (r==0)

{

NSString *randomResponse = [arrayName objectAtIndex:0];

[[self myWebView] loadHTMLString:randomResponse baseURL:nil];     

}
```

Comment: can't you just shuffle the array and iterate through it?

Answer (score 0):

Just create an ivar or property that keeps track of the previous object if you need to go back.
If need more, make a simple stack using an array, that tracks x number of previous objects.
You can find them in the new sorted/shuffle array by using indexOfObject